# Помощь с multipart/form-data

Tags: php, curl, forms

Помогите пожалуйста, как можно передать вот такие данные с помощью php cURL упрощённо:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="YII_CSRF_TOKEN"

dc757ad2e3d6523231c82e302d377e3b6ba702f2
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="widgetId"

messager
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[network]"

38050
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[phone]"

546-45-65
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[encoding]"

cyrilic
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[is_translit]"

0
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[message]"

ваиави
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[verifyCode]"

930
------WebKitFormBoundarymTkgTwzpBHQLP12d--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Касательно именно PHP cURL:

Если вам не принципиален конкретный `boundary` (т.к. его положено генерировать случайным образом), то будет достаточно банального:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'widgetId' => 'messager',
    'MessageForm[id]' => 1,
    // ну и аналогично
]);
```

Сгенерирует запрос вроде такого:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 256
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a

--------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="widgetId"

messager
--------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MessageForm[id]"

1
--------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a--
```

Если `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` передать массив, то `multipart/form-data` генерируется по-умолчанию.

Если необходимо с какой-либо целью разделитель контролировать - то придётся тело сообщения форматировать самостоятельно в большую строку, но передавать всё тому же `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Если в этот параметр передаётся строка - то она отправляется как есть.

Answer (score 1):

например так

```
curl -X POST -H "<header_#_1> : <header_#_1_value>" -H "<header_#_2> : <header_#_2_value>" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 58708f45-232e-e4d1-8dd7-1728e0c32a77" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "file=@<path_to_my_file>" "<my_url>"
```