# Что это за параметры в POST?

Tags: php, post, параметры

У меня при нажатие на кнопку "сохранить" на сервер отправляется запрос , это письмо из редактора Tinymce с картинками.
На сервер в этот момент передаются параметры

```
-----------------------------28257400717280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="act"

save_tmp
-----------------------------28257400717280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

1|1|1
-----------------------------28257400717280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mail_body"

<p><img src="\&quot;file.1.png\&quot;" /><img src="\&quot;\\&quot;file.1.png\\&quot;\&quot;" /><img src="\&quot;\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;file.1.png\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\&quot;" /><img src="\&quot;\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\\\\\\\&quot;file.1.png\\\\\\\\&quot;\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\&quot;" /><img src="\&quot;\\&quot;\\\\&quot;file.1.png\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\&quot;" /></p>
-----------------------------28257400717280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attach"

-----------------------------28257400717280
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hdir"

17.05.2018
-----------------------------28257400717280--
```

Что это за параметры? и самое главное как их поправить. возле имени файла постоянно подставляются &quot и слеши, мне нужно их убрать ,чтобы было

```
     <img src="file.1.jpg">
```

Что? какую строку искать в скриптах?

Вот форма

```
<form id="mce" name="mce">

               <table id="mheader" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td id="msubj">
                Тема письма<br>
                <input id="msubj" type="text">
            </td><td id="mfromtxt">
                От кого<br>
                <input id="mfromtxt" type="text">
            </td><td id="mfrommail">
                E-mail отправителя<br>
                <input id="mfrommail" type="text">
            </td></tr></tbody></table>

            <div id="mceu_23" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="application" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px;"><div id="mceu_23-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout"><div id="mceu_24" class="mce-toolbar-grp mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group"><div id="mceu_24-body" class="mce-container-body mce-stack-layout"><div id="mceu_25" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-first" role="toolbar"><div id="mceu_25-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout"><div id="mceu_26" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_26-body"><div id="mceu_0" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_0" role="button" aria-label="Source code"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-code"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_1" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_1" role="button" aria-label="Preview"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-preview"></i></button></div></div></div><div id="mceu_27" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_27-body"><div id="mceu_2" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-first mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_2" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"><button id="mceu_2-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><span class="mce-txt">Формат</span> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_3" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-fixed-width mce-listbox mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_3" role="button" aria-label="Font Sizes" aria-haspopup="true"><button id="mceu_3-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><span class="mce-txt">Размер шрифта</span> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_4" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn mce-fixed-width mce-listbox mce-last mce-btn-has-text" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_4" role="button" aria-label="Font Family" aria-haspopup="true"><button id="mceu_4-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><span class="mce-txt">Шрифт</span> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div></div></div><div id="mceu_28" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_28-body"><div id="mceu_5" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_5" role="button" aria-label="Horizontal line"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-hr"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_6" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-menubtn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_6" role="button" aria-label="Table" aria-haspopup="true"><button id="mceu_6-open" role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-table"></i> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_7" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_7" role="button" aria-label="Insert/edit link"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-link"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_8" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_8" role="button" aria-label="Remove link"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-unlink"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_9" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_9" role="button" aria-label="Insert/edit image"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-image"></i></button></div></div></div></div></div><div id="mceu_29" class="mce-container mce-toolbar mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" role="toolbar"><div id="mceu_29-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout"><div id="mceu_30" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-first mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_30-body"><div id="mceu_10" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_10" role="button" aria-label="Clear formatting"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-removeformat"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_11" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_11" role="button" aria-label="Bold"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bold"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_12" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_12" role="button" aria-label="Italic"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-italic"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_13" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-colorbutton" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Text color"><button role="presentation" hidefocus="1" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-forecolor"></i><span id="mceu_13-preview" class="mce-preview"></span></button><button type="button" class="mce-open" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_14" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-colorbutton mce-last" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-label="Background color"><button role="presentation" hidefocus="1" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-backcolor"></i><span id="mceu_14-preview" class="mce-preview"></span></button><button type="button" class="mce-open" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div></div></div><div id="mceu_31" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_31-body"><div id="mceu_15" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_15" role="button" aria-label="Align left"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignleft"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_16" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_16" role="button" aria-label="Align center"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-aligncenter"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_17" class="mce-widget mce-btn" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_17" role="button" aria-label="Align right"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignright"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_18" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_18" role="button" aria-label="Justify"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-alignjustify"></i></button></div></div></div><div id="mceu_32" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_32-body"><div id="mceu_19" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-splitbtn mce-menubtn mce-first" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Bullet list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-bullist"></i></button><button type="button" class="mce-open" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_20" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-splitbtn mce-menubtn mce-last" role="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Numbered list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-numlist"></i></button><button type="button" class="mce-open" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1"> <i class="mce-caret"></i></button></div></div></div><div id="mceu_33" class="mce-container mce-flow-layout-item mce-last mce-btn-group" role="group"><div id="mceu_33-body"><div id="mceu_21" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-first" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_21" role="button" aria-label="Decrease indent"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-outdent"></i></button></div><div id="mceu_22" class="mce-widget mce-btn mce-last" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="mceu_22" role="button" aria-label="Increase indent"><button role="presentation" type="button" tabindex="-1"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-indent"></i></button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="mceu_34" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"><iframe id="mce_0_ifr" allowtransparency="true" title="Текстовое поле. Нажмите ALT-F9 чтобы вызвать меню, ALT-F10 панель инструментов, ALT-0 для вызова помощи." style="width: 100%; height: 300px; display: block;" src="javascript:&quot;&quot;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><div id="mceu_35" class="mce-statusbar mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item mce-last" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"><div id="mceu_35-body" class="mce-container-body mce-flow-layout"><div id="mceu_36" class="mce-path mce-flow-layout-item mce-first"><div role="button" class="mce-path-item mce-last" data-index="0" tabindex="-1" id="mceu_36-0" aria-level="0">p</div></div><div id="mceu_37" class="mce-flow-layout-item mce-last mce-resizehandle"><i class="mce-ico mce-i-resize"></i></div></div></div></div></div><textarea id="mce_0" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>

            <div id="mfiles"><span id="mfile"><span id="mfile_name" onclick="in_to(&quot;file.1.png&quot;)">file.1.png</span><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fdel(&quot;file.1.png&quot;,&quot;delete&quot;);" title="Удалить">Х</a><input id="mfile_name" title="Прикрепить" value="file.1.png" type="checkbox"></span></div>

            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td width="50%">
                <input id="mfile" class="upload" accept=".doc,.pdf,.docx,.txt,.png,image/*" type="file">
            </td><td style="text-align: right;">
                <input id="mfile" class="save" value="Сохранить" type="button">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td><td style="text-align: right;">
                <input id="mfile" class="ready" value="Готово" type="button">
            </td></tr></tbody></table>

        </form>
```

Вот var_dump($_POST) по нажатию на кнопку

```
array(5) { ["act"]=> string(8) "save_tmp" ["headers"]=> string(59)     "Тестовое письмо|test@test.ru|testmail@test.ru" ["mail_body"]=> string(34) "
1" ["attach"]=> string(0) "" ["hdir"]=> string(10) "17.05.2018" }
```

Comment: код формы и код на сервере какой?

Comment: Для начала покажите, как вы составляете и отправляете запрос

Comment: вы лучше смотрите, что у вас на стороне сервера в `print_r($_POST)` приходит, а не то что браузер рисует при отправке в сетевой активности.

Comment: @teran, я добавил вывод $_POST

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype тип запроса `multipart/form-data`

Comment: вы хреновый `$_POST` указали, скопируйте его не со страницы, где тэги не видны,  а из просмотра кода страницы. Увидите, что там с вашими кавычками все в порядке.

Comment: хотя может и нет. зачем у вас в коде эти `&quot;` прописаны вообще? используйте одинарную кавычку

Comment: Скорее всего у вас битый файл. Покажите первые 16 байт и текстом и если можно в hex форме (hiew или far отображают heх).

Answer (score 0):

Типы post запроса. Существует как минимум 3 (три) типа кодирования данных в post-запросе. В вашем случае ваш тип укажу первым. Тип пост-запроса можно указать в теге `<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>` например, тогда запрос генерирует браузер. Если пишется свой клиент - то прийдётся сформировать запрос с структурой характерной для этого типа POST запроса.

- **multipart/form-data** выглядит он так.

  ```
  POST / HTTP/1.1
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
  Accept: */*
  Content-Length: 256
  Expect: 100-continue
  Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------  5e95fe2dd0851b9a

  --------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="widgetId"

  messager
  --------------------------5e95fe2dd0851b9a
  ```

  Запрос взял [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547467/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-multipart-form-data) для примера. этот вид запроса часто используется, т.к. с его помощью можно отправлять файлы на сервер. Другие виды запросов не могут передавать файлы (т.к. файл может исказится). `boundary=` задаёт длинный разделитель, что позволяет избежать "неоднозначности". Данные браузер передаёт в чистом виде (без использования urlencoding или "escape-инга"). Т.е. этот метод передачи не искажает данные вообще.
- **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**  Передача параметров в виде url-encoded, т.е. запрос имеет вид

  ```
  POST / HTTP/1.1
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
  Accept: */*
  Content-Length: 28

  param1=value&param2=value%2F
  ```

  т.е. как в get-запросе без знака вопроса, служебные символы кодируются через %. Т.е. данные проходят urlencode (или escape устар.). В редких случаях могут возникать проблемы с кодировкой, если кодовая страница urlencode допустим 1251 на клиенте, а сервер ожидает UTF-8. этот вид передачи запроса вам покажется очень знакомым. Если вы хотите переключиться на этот тип - укажите `<from enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` в параметрах формы.
- **text/plain**
  Пробелы заменяются знаком +, буквы и другие символы не кодируются. Не встречал использование этого метода.
- **text/json** 
  Контент запроса передаётся в виде JSON. это сравнительно новый тип. Про поддержку не могу сказать. этот метод используется, особенно для обмена "подзапросами", например ajax. Файл этот метод не может передавать, а если закодировать его в base64 то... передаётся текст.

Если используется php c# или другие языки web-программирования - у них при подготовке запроса данные с "контента" сами переписываются в переменные, и как правило через  `$_POST`(php)  `Request`(c#) их можна получить. Для получения файлов используются файловые функции. Среда сама по `Content-Type` видит тип запроса и декодирует его.

Для php вам достаточно написать `$_POST["act"]` и вы получите `save_tmp`.

Comment: а как поправить то его? это точно php посылает, или это javascript?

Comment: @Dmitriy это браузер посылает на сервер

Comment: @Dmitriy попробуйте явно указать второй метод - тогда вам будет передан запрос в "привычной" (как я думаю) для вас форме.

Comment: @Dmitriy Стоп, я ошибся.. у вас используются файлы - вам подходит только первый метод.

Comment: *и самое главное как их поправить. возле имени файла постоянно подставляются &quot и слеши, мне нужно их убрать* -  у вас проблема с самим файлом, который вы передаёте на сервер. Клиент не умеет "портить" файлы. В редких случаях сама среда (php) может портить файл, но php по умолчанию не конвертирует " в quote